# int main is looping for no apparent reason? (PIC programming, XC16, MPLAB) dsPIC33EP

Tags: c, loops, pic, microchip, mplab

Working on a program to run on a dcPIC33 (coded in c obviously) using the XC16 compiler and MPLABX v2.10 IDE. I have implemented some functionality, one function of which is to send strings of text to a uart so i can see serial output using a serial terminal. My problem is found in this line.

```
UART_Write_Text("Starting ADXL345 test...fdsbjugbbjkdsf");
```

Which when you look at the below code should only run once however it is forever repeated in the terminal as if the int main fer looping, even though the main has a while loop at the bottom to keep it from ending i just can't see how it is managing to loop like this.

```
    /* 
 * File:   main2.c
 * Author: nedu
 *
 * Created on 14 July 2014, 15:57
 */
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if __XC16_VERSION < 1011
#warning "Please upgrade to XC16 v1.11 or newer."
#endif

#pragma config ICS = PGD3           // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC3 and PGED3)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF         // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)

// FPOR
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF        // Alternate I2C1 pins (I2C1 mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config ALTI2C2 = OFF        // Alternate I2C2 pins (I2C2 mapped to SDA2/SCL2 pins)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25       // Watchdog Window Select bits (WDT Window is 25% of WDT period)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128       // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON          // PLL Lock Enable bit (Clock switch to PLL source will wait until the PLL lock signal is valid.)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF         // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF         // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (Watchdog timer enabled/disabled by user software)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE          // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (XT Crystal Oscillator Mode)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF       // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF        // Peripheral pin select configuration (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD       // Clock Switching Mode bits (Clock switching is enabled,Fail-safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC          // Oscillator Source Selection (Internal Fast RC (FRC))
#pragma config IESO = OFF           // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up with user-selected oscillator source)

// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF           // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GCP = OFF            // General Segment Code-Protect bit (General Segment Code protect is Disabled)

#define FP 40000000
#define BAUDRATE 9600
#define BRGVAL ((FP/BAUDRATE)/16)-1
#define DELAY_105uS asm volatile ("REPEAT, #4201"); Nop(); // 105uS delay

unsigned int i;
char *temp[40];

#include "spi.h"
#include "ADXL345.h"

void delay_ms(long ms){
    unsigned long x = 0;
    for(x = 0; x <= ((FP/24000))*ms; x++)
        Nop();
}
void __attribute__((__interrupt__)) _U1TXInterrupt(void)
{
    IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0; // Clear TX Interrupt flag
}

void UART_Write(char data)
{
    while(!U1STAbits.TRMT);
    U1TXREG = data;
}

void UART_Write_Text(char *text)
{
    int i;
    UART_Write('\n');
    UART_Write('\r');
    for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
        UART_Write(text[i]);
}

void InitClock(){
    PLLFBD=63; // M=65
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0; // N2=2
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=1; // N1=3
    // Initiate Clock Switch to FRC oscillator with PLL (NOSC=0b001)
    __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x01);
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01);
    // Wait for Clock switch to occur
    while (OSCCONbits.COSC!= 0b001);
    // Wait for PLL to lock
    while (OSCCONbits.LOCK!= 1);
}

void InitUart(){
    U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0; // 1-Stop bit
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0; // No Parity, 8-Data bits
    U1MODEbits.ABAUD = 0; // Auto-Baud disabled
    U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0; // Standard-Speed mode
    U1BRG = BRGVAL; // Baud Rate setting for 9600
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL0 = 0; // Interrupt after one TX character is transmitted
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0;
    IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 1; // Enable UART TX interrupt
    RPOR4bits.RP43R = 1;    //RP43/RB11 as U1TX
    RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 42; //RP42/RB10 as U1RX
    U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1; // Enable UART
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1; // Enable UART TX
    /* Wait at least 105 microseconds (1/9600) before sending first char */
    DELAY_105uS
}

int main(void)
{
    InitClock();
    InitUart();

    spi_init();
    UART_Write_Text("Starting ADXL345 test...fdsbjugbbjkdsf");
    enable_adxl345();
    int id = adxl345_devID();
    sprintf(temp, "Device ID is: 0x%02x", id);
    UART_Write_Text(temp);
    UART_Write_Text("Done");


    /*
    //Go into standby mode to configure the device.
    setPowerControl(0x00);

    //Full resolution, +/-16g, 4mg/LSB.
    setDataFormatControl(0x0B);

    //3.2kHz data rate.
    setDataRate(ADXL345_3200HZ);

    //Measurement mode.
    setPowerControl(0x08);
    */
    int* readings[3] = {0,0,0};
    getOutput(readings);
    int inter = 7;

    while(1)
    {
        delay_ms(1000);
        /*UART_Write_Text("Starting ADXL345 test...");*/
        sprintf(temp, "%i, %i, %i", inter, (int) readings[1], (int) readings[2]);
        UART_Write_Text("WORK");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Terminal output received]

I just can't figure it out, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:
Managed to fix my problem, the reason for the program crashing was the for loop in the function UART_Write_Text() (The one commented out below).

```
void UART_Write(char data)
{
    while(!U1STAbits.TRMT);
    U1TXREG = data;
}

void UART_Write_Text(char *text)
{
    int i;
    UART_Write('\n');
    UART_Write('\r');

    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
        UART_Write(text[i]);
    /*
    for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
        UART_Write(text[i]);
    */
}
```

The for loop condition text[I]!='\0', I used '\0' to stop looping at the end of the char[] however I was under the assumption that '\0' meant a char that = NULL when for the condition to actually be met, there actually had to = '\0'.

Although no answer managed to catch this I would like to thank everyone who took their time to try and help me out on this and I have upvoted you all as all your answers helped in my understanding of C as a whole, since I have the opportunity to mark a question as answered im going to mark "gmch"'s answer as his explanation on the difference between an array of variables and an array of pointers to said variables is stellar in my opinion :).

Comment: It probably is running only once -- the program is being re-run when it crashes because it reboots.

Comment: I think you are right, i beleive the problem has somthing to do with the UART_Write_Text(char *text); function i just can't figure it out yet..

Comment: `#define DELAY_105uS asm volatile ("REPEAT, #4201"); Nop(); // 105uS delay` is not guaranteed to work properly; you cannot assume the compiler will produce a `NOP` instruction right after the `REPEAT` instruction, so the correct approach is to put the `NOP` inside the `asm()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int* readings[3] = {0,0,0};` is an array of pointers to integers... which is probably why you `(int)readings[1]` to stop the compiler whining at you.

I cannot see a `getOutput()` so cannot see what it will do with `getOutput(readings)`, but if it wants an array of pointers to int, then you are giving it three 0 pointers -- which may be bad.

As noted elsewhere, `char *temp[40]` is similarly an array of pointers to `char`, not an array of 40 chars.

---

C is seriously baffling when it comes to arrays and pointers, not least because the name of the array is implicitly a pointer to the first element of an array, and (conversely) a pointer can be used as if it was an array.  And "strings" just add to the confusion.  So in...

```
int readings[3] = { 11, 22, 33 } ;
int* p ;
```

we have an array of three integers, called `readings` intialised as shown, and a pointer to integer `p', with no value.  Now:

```
readings[2] += 1 ;
```

adds 1 to `readings[2]` making `23`.  And we can:

```
p = readings ;
```

So now `p` points at the `readings[0]` -- because the name of the array automagically works like a pointer to the start of the array.  We could also have written:

```
p = &readings[0] ;
```

which you could argue is clearer... and is consistent with:

```
p = &readings[1] ;
```

Interestingly, you can write:

```
p[1] += 1 ;
```

('cos pointers and arrays are -- largely -- interchangable), which will set `readings[2]` to `33'.

In fact the following all refer to `readings[2]`:

```
*(p+1) 
p[1]
readings[2]
*(readings+2)
```

It gets better... when you (apparently) pass an array to a function, you are actually passing a pointer to the first element of the array.  So your function can be:

```
static void foo(int* z) .....
static void foo(int a[]) .....
```

and the effect is the same.  You can call it:

```
foo(readings) ;
foo(p) ;
```

and in the function itself `a[2]` `*(a+2)` `z[2]` `*(z+2)` are pretty much interchangeable.

As a rule I think of a definition:

char bar[22] ;

as creating a `char*` (pseudo) pointer called `bar` which implicitly points to a the first element of an array of 22 chars.  If I also create:

```
char* pc = bar ;
```

then that's created a (real) pointer, also initialised to point at the first element of the array of 22 chars.  The difference between `bar` and `pc` are small: (1) you cannot assign to `bar` -- it is, effectively `const`; (2) `sizeof(bar)` gives the size of the **array**, but `sizeof(pc)` gives the size of the **pointer**.

Answer (score 1):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, which will lead to weird things happening (most often crashes).

The problem is your definition of the variable `temp` and how you use it. You use it as a string in your `sprintf` call, but it's defined as an *array* of strings.

Comment: Its an array or chars, which makes up a string? or should i be going about this another way? as i have to use an array of chars when writing to the UART.

Comment: @sp10acnFIFO Look at the declaration of `temp` again, its an array (because of the `[40]`) of pointers (because of the `*`) to `char`. In other words, you have an array of 40 pointers to `char`. If you want a plain string that can contain up to 39 characters (remember the string terminator must be there too) just do `char temp[40]` (note the absence of the asterisk).

Comment: I have tried removing the * to just parse a char[], however im still confused as to the looping of the text shown as that particualr line isnt writing the char[] to the UART. perhaps its something to do with the UART_Write_Text function taking arguments (char *text)?

Comment: @sp10acnFIFO After the change, does it still loop? If it doesn't then it's simply because of the undefined behavior cause the program to behave in undefined ways.

Comment: It still loops, i tried commenting out all code in the main except InitClock();
    InitUart();

    spi_init();
    UART_Write_Text("Starting ADXL345 test...fdsbjugbbjkdsf"); Still loops

Comment: As @Billy Pilgrim stated could it be the UART_Write_Text function crashing the program and thus rebooting to make it appear its looping?

Answer (score 1):

As general recommendation: split your program by parts, devide the whole to by 2 or exclude function by function (calls). Probably start with simple loop `usngined long i = 0; while (1) { printf("%x ",i); i++; }` in order to be sure the watchdog timer `pragma` applied. Then exclude others. Otherwise you can only analyse code and docs.